# Semantic issue control may reach end of non-void function

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm creating a recipes app and have run into this semantic issue in the number of rows in section method of my table view. This is the first time I've really worked with table Views and I'm wondering if someone could perhaps see what I've done wrong and point me in the right direction. Thanks!

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    if (menuInt == 0)
        return [soupsArray count];
    if (menuInt == 1)
        return [saladsArray count];
    if (menuInt == 2)
        return [appetizersArray count];
    if (menuInt == 3)
        return [entreeArray count];
    if (menuInt == 4)
        return [dissertsArray count];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: You should not call reloadData from within numberOfRowsInSection.

Answer (score 3):

What happens if all the if conditions fail? You need to make sure that you at least return an NSInteger even though you are sure one of the if conditions will succeed for sure. That's just how it is.

Also, as Martin R pointed out, you should not have reloadData in the function.

Answer (score 0):

try one of these 2 solutions (the reload data must occur before the return statement also)

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
int counter = 0;
// Return the number of rows in the section.
if (menuInt == 0)
    counter = [soupsArray count];
if (menuInt == 1)
    counter = [saladsArray count];
if (menuInt == 2)
    counter = [appetizersArray count];
if (menuInt == 3)
    counter = [entreeArray count];
if (menuInt == 4)
    counter = [dissertsArray count];

[self.tableView reloadData];
return counter;
```

}

or

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

// Return the number of rows in the section.
if (menuInt == 0) {
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    return [soupsArray count];
}
 else if (menuInt == 1) {
[self.tableView reloadData];
    return [saladsArray count];
}
 else if (menuInt == 2) {
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    return [appetizersArray count];
}
 else if (menuInt == 3) {
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    return [entreeArray count];
}
 else if (menuInt == 4) {
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    return [dissertsArray count];
else {
    [self.tableview reloadData];
    return 0;
}
```

}

Comment: The first solution will return uninitialized memory if all the `if`s fail. `int counter = 0;` would fix it and make it equivalent to your second solution.